# Configuring Intellij IDEA to use Kdiff3 as merge program

Tags: intellij-idea, merge, kdiff3

I would like to know the correct parameters to be passed to Kdiff3 from Intellij IDEA's external diff tools menu in order to use Kdiff3 for merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters are:

```
%3 %2 %1 -o %4
```

Parameters `%2` and `%1` are interchangeable. `%1` is for local changes and `%2` are the changes in the base branch.

Considering [kdiff3 documentation](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html)

> Merging 3 files:
>
> `kdiff3 file1 file2 file3 -m`
>
> `kdiff3 file1 file2 file3 -o outputfile`
>
> Note that *file1* will be treated as base of *file2* and *file3*.

For Intellij, `%3` is the base version. `%1` are the changes in the branch you are rebasing, `%2` are the changes in the new base branch.

*Intellij 2016.2 Ultimate edition*

[image]

Comment: %3 is the server content and base version is %2 (at least on version 13.1.6)

Comment: @Alfergon I guess the order changed at some point. Just added the screenshot with the current values.

Answer (score 3):

At some point, the correct parameters were:

```
%2 %1 %3 -o %4
```

See the accepted answer for current values.

Answer (score 1):

With Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1 (which is based on IntelliJ 2017.1) these values work for me:

- external diff parameters: `%3 %1 %2`
- external merge parameters: `%3 %1 %2 -o %4`
  [image]